# loading the mysql module

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am 85 and trying to keep my brain active by converting a php/mysql page, that i wrote to node.js.
`require 'mysql';`
I have the nodejs server up and running. it delivers, correctly, an html page i wrote. i 'require fs' and get it but i cannot find a mysql module. when i npm mysql it fails with a warning of deprecation. my question is how can i get 'mysql' installed so that i can 'require' it? is there a 'mysql' module that i can downlod and place in the c:/nodejs/node_modules folder? Naive?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mysql

Answer (score 0):

I have been learning node.js for months. Hopefully I can help:

1. Check your "package.json" in the code editor (VS Code/Atom).
2. Check whether "mysql" version in "dependencies" or not.
3. If no, go to terminal, type "npm install mysql".
4. After completion, it should have included in "dependencies".
5. Require mysql in your mysql database connection file (Example: const mysql = require("mysql");)
6. I think it should be working fine already.

You can always remove existing mysql by typing npm remove mysql in the terminal then go back to Step 3 to reinstall it.

Hope it helps. Thanks